# (java) Can't check if ArrayList contains a specific String

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contains

There is this problem that i have been stuck with for hours. 
I'm trying to check an ArrayList for a specific String.

This is the ArrayList i am checking:

```
public ArrayList getAllowedPlayers() {
    return this.allowedPlayers;
}
```

The username's get added in lower case to this list.

Then this is what i use to check if the player typing the command is on the list:

```
 boolean addedToSSList = data.getAllowedPlayers().contains(astring[0].toLowerCase());
```

"data" refers to the ArrayList of the username that has been entered (astring[0]). Which is in another class.
Then i use a print to chat message to check if the boolean turns true or false, which always returns false in my case.

```
        icommandsender.sendChatToPlayer("addedToList: "+addedToSSList);
```

However, i can see that the username entered is added to the list with:

```
        icommandsender.sendChatToPlayer("Allowed players: "+data.getAllowedPlayers())
```

The player from icommandsender is the person using the command to see if he is on the ArrayList.

So basically:
I can see that the Username i am entering is on the ArrayList (in lowercase). The astring[0] is this username in lowercase that i entered. But my boolean method will still return false.

Comment: Maybe you have leading/trailing spaces that you don't see.

Comment: do this `astring[0].toLowerCase().trim()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
boolean addedToSSList = data.getAllowedPlayers().contains(astring[0].toLowerCase().trim());
```

May be you have some trailing spaces in your string.

**EDIT:**

```
public boolean findString(String s, ArrayList<String> al){
     for (String str : al){
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
            return true;
         }
     }
    return false;
  }
```

and then you can find like

```
findString("myString", yourArrayList);
```

Comment: The command string always is "username" without spaces so this wont change anything. 
But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user3482325:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: Got it working, thank you!

Main problem however was that my astring[0] was the username entered, not the players username that is typing the command. Oops.